# sqlite database is locked exception

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am using c# application and running the application in server machine as windows service.When i perform insert , update delete operation from client machine it throws database lock error as below,

```
database is locked
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Step(SQLiteStatement stmt)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteTransaction.Commit()
```

Below is my code

```
public int ExecuteNonQuerySQL(SQLiteCommand cmd)
   {
        int ireturn = 0;
         if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
               Open(DataFile);
          using (SQLiteTransaction dbtrans = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
            {
                  using (cmd.Connection=conn)
                    {
                         cmd.CommandText =cmd.CommandText ;
                          cmd.Transaction = dbtrans;
                           ireturn = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                           dbtrans.Commit();
                           cmd.Dispose();
                        }
                   }
               }
```

Please help me in this , I have done lot of googling and i must find some solution to solve this .
Regards

Comment: Seems that you not closing connection.

Comment: Before Execute nonquery performed , the db connection is closed and reopen again..

Comment: And after it? Lock exception might be because when you open db connection it locks file. You need to release lock - close connection. So ensure that you really close connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code provided it *seems* that you do not close the connecttion.

Pay attention also on fact, don't know if it's relevant in your case or not, that the `Sqlite` not very good on supporting concurent `inserts` and sometimes db got lock, if you operate on it from multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

Change the way you create your Connection and Command objects to be more like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17592858/8479

Make sure you're not re-using any Sqlite object on a different thread to the one it was created on.

Sqlite is normally great at concurrency provided you follow those two rules.

Answer (score 0):

In my case closing the connection was not an issue.
The issue was i was opening and closing connection for each Table although the database was same.
So do not open connection multiple times for the same database in SQlite.

- Open Connection
- Do your all of your transactions in just that opened connection.
- Close connection.

SQlite is not good at handling this. So if you cannot afford that solution its better to use a Server like SQLServer etc.